# Website looking really weird

Tags: html, css

Why is my paragraph bigger than the div when its inside it. To me it doesn't make any sense. Can you guys explain why this is happening and how I can fix it.

CSS:

```
  #whos{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="Text">

 <b id="bold">Hello,my name is Navjeeven</b>

 <p id="whos">
  I am Currently enrolled at
  <a href="https://www.bramptoncs.org">Brampton Christian School</a>
  </p>

 </div>
```

[What it looks like right now?](http://www.jeevenmann.ca)

Comment: As aside note, I would suggest looking into some CSS naming conventions. Having an id of "bold" to use once to make one element bold is extremely bad architecture, and will only lead to more problems which don't make any sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have another style: `#inside p` which overrides the font size.

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/